# Confusing Typescript Interface behaviour

Tags: typescript

** Code 1: **

```
interface Point {
x: number;
y: number;
}

function logPoint(p: Point) {
console.log(`${p.x}, ${p.y}`);
}

// logs "12, 26"
const point = { x: 12, y: 26, z:"newfield" };
logPoint(point);
```

---

**Code 2: **

```
interface SquareConfig {
color?: string;
width?: number;
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig) {
return {
color: config.color || "red",
area: config.width ? config.width \* config.width : 20,
};
}

let mySquare = createSquare({ color: "red", width: 100 ,  z:"newfield"});
```

I'm getting the following error in the code 2 but not in code 1.
`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'z' does not exist in type 'SquareConfig'.`

Can someone please explain this behavior to me?

I was expecting why this is behaving differently.

Edit :

I noticed this strange behavior
In code 2  If we call createSquare following way Error disappeared

```
const val = { color: "red", width: 100, z:"newfield"}
 
let mySquare = createSquare(val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have not defined `z` in your `SquareConfig` type, therefore adding `z` is considered "not allowed" by the compiler.

If you added `z` to the `SquareConfig` the compiler would not throw this error at you

```js
interface SquareConfig {
color?: string;
width?: number;
z?: string
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig) {
return {
color: config.color || "red",
area: config.width ? config.width: 20,
};
}

let mySquare = createSquare({ color: "red", width: 100 ,  z:"newfield"});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoEcCucoQMID2IMwA5sgN4BQCBANgVAPwBcyAzmFKKQNxUB3YABMwAC1bIQmALYAjaPwBekztxCkqAXypUYmEAjDAiyBLjiQM2XAApaxMm2s58REqQCUlKrjCYoEB9aBig2Bw8AOhDGZAAfOOQAIlxhJIAaKlc4cPcySKFRMWQmMzzSApFxNgAmAAZMrX4dKjoIMGQZAE8XXGQAXjMLKyxXWwoy0LYUiDT05ELq5ABGOrrkeeQlFiSQCAESCDo0rU9eIA)

Edit:

The compiler is reading your `SquareConfig` and then sees you call `createSquare`, and says, "well you can't do that because `z` wasn't defined in that type so you can't add it in now"

Conversely, if you didn't define `z`, but then you were trying to access it inside `createSquare`, then the compiler would say pretty much the same, "you can't access this `z` property because I don't know what that is since it doesn't exist in `SquareConfig`"

These are not verbatim messages.

#### Edit to address code 1

In code 1, the compiler is being a bit more relaxed with you because `z` is being defined in `const point`, but that is an Object but hasn't been defined as `Point`.

This throws an error because `Point` cannot have `z`.

```js
const point:Point = { x: 12, y: 26, z:"newfield" };
```

However the compiler lets you get away with it here because the the object `point` contains all the keys necessary for `logPoint`

```js
function logPoint(p: Point) {
console.log(`${p.x}, ${p.y}`);
}

// logs "12, 26"
const point = { x: 12, y: 26, z:"newfield" };
logPoint(point);
```

Comment: I have also not added `Z in the Point interface` and  const point = { x: 12, y: 26, z:"newfield" };
logPoint(point); -> This works fine

Comment: "*therefore adding z is considered "not allowed" by the compiler.*" that is **only** when [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) trigger which is under specific circumstances. Otherwise TS does  not flag an error if some interface has *more* properties than another type. They are assignable to one another, the same way `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal` and thus assignable.

Comment: Yes OP, you're right, I've updated my answer to reflect that, essentially the compiler is being more lenient with you since `const point` contains enough keys to satisfy `logPoint`

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the error occurs when you pass the data directly in the method parameter. It doesn't occur in code 1, because you stored the data in a variable, then passed that variable to your method.

Here is a REPL that shows that : https://replit.com/@billuc/TestTypescriptInterfaces#index.ts

I added a third bit of code where I created a config an stored it in a variable. I then called createSquare with that variableand didn't get an error.

BTW, the error only appears in the editor, I don't get it while running the code.